# fgets adds an extra line to output file?

Tags: php, fwrite, fgets

The code below outputs a nicely formatted text file.  But it also adds an additional character at the end of the text file - I assume a \r or \n character.  I have tried sed '$d' but that does not work.  When I open the output file (load_data_infile.txt) in an editor, and I position my cursor after the last written line of the file, it says I am on line "15 of 14" which is odd.  How can I can have 15 lines in a 14 line file?

My questions are these: 1) what is causing line "15 of 14" and 2) how can I prevent it being written OR remove it once it is?

Thanks!

```
    <?php

$file_write_output = fopen("load_data_infile.txt", "w") or die ("can't open load_data_infile.txt for writing");
$file_read_input = fopen("http://file.txt", "r") or die ("can't open file");

//perform the loop through the file - read the input file line by line with fgets function

while (!feof($file_read_input) ) {

$input = fgets($file_read_input);


echo "$input";

fwrite($file_write_output,$input);

}

fclose($file_write_output);

fclose($file_read_input);

?>

<?php

//strip out the header of load_data_infile.txt file


exec("sed -i '1d' load_data_infile.txt");


?>
```

Comment: I don't believe fwrite() to write anything else than the data read in.

Comment: If you are using unix you can use `ls -l` to check that the lenghts are the same. `od -c ` will display the characters and convert spaces\unprintable ones into something that you can see.

Comment: Hi, thank you - is od -c performed at the command line?  do I need to specify the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://file.txt');

if ($file !== false) {
    return $file;
}

if ( file_put_contents('load_data_infile.txt', $content, LOCK_EX) ) {
    // Success
}
```

PHP Documentation:
[PHP file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
and [PHP file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Thank you - does this replace my loop?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working!

```
<?php
    $raw_data = file_get_contents('http://file.txt');
    $trimmed_raw_data=trim($raw_data);
    echo $trimmed_raw_data;
    if (file_put_contents('load_data_infile.txt', $trimmed_raw_data, LOCK_EX) ) 
?>
```